# A deceptively difficult linear recurrence problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-transformations, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence $b_0 = 0$, $b_1 = 1$, $b_{n+2} = 2b_{n+1} - 3b_n$ for all $n\geq 0$. Prove that the only positive integers $m$ with $b_m = \pm 1$ are $m = 1$ and $m = 3$. (In fact, I expect that $b_m = -1$ never occurs but not proving this is not an issue for the purpose described below.)

Calculating the first $50$ terms does not give much of a hint since the sequence is quite oscillating above and below $0$ and even $|b_n|$ is not monotonic all the time. An explicit formula is $b_n = (\sqrt{3})^n\frac{\sin(n \cdot \arctan \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}$ (derived by solving the characteristic equation etc.) but it does not really help me either.

(Interesting context: if one proves this, then it is not hard to prove, using $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, that the only positive integer solutions to $x^2 + 2 = 3^n$ are $(1,1)$ and $(5,3)$.)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The best idea I can think of is to try to use modular arithmetic. If there is a point where you get two multiples of $k>1$ in a row then it can never hit $\pm1$ after that.

Comment: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s1-39.1.537  I dimly remember a discussion that indicated that methods changed a good deal for  $x_{n+2}  = A x_{n+1} + B x_n$  when $A,B$  are not both positive; names such as Mordell, Nagell,

Comment: @WillJagy I haven't read the paper yet, but the title and preview doesn't seem relevant. Is there something later on?

Comment: $b_2=2,b_3=1,b_4=-4$.  Question?

Comment: this was my similar MO question...  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355565/finding-all-squares-in-a-generalized-fibonacci-type-sequence  Here we go, Petho  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X82900798?via%3Dihub

Comment: I just ran a python program over the first $50,000$ entries or so, no $\pm1$ or divisiblity results.  If it does hit $\pm1$ I would be surprised, but of course this isn't a proof.

Comment: Again this isn't a proof, but by messing around with approximating $\pi$ by $n\arctan(\sqrt2)$ we can say that (in a certain sense) almost surely there are only finitely many cases where $b_n=\pm1$. I got this result using Khinchin's theorem. As this is a comment I won't give the full details. Wikipedia gives the details on Khinchin's theorem the rest is using the fact that $n\arctan(\sqrt2)$ needs to be very close to $\pi$ for large $n$. Also this suggests that looking at diophantine approximations of $\frac{\arctan(\sqrt2)}{\pi}$ might be a good method of proving this.

Comment: Using more diophantine approximation stuff (assuming I understand it correctly) and Wolfram alpha, the first possible occurance of a $1$ would be at least at $n=2.5344\times10^{56}$. Additionally for a $1$ to occur here the $101$st convergent of the continued fraction of $\frac{\arctan(\sqrt2)}{\pi}$ would have to have a denominator on the order of $10^{10^{55}}$. If I can get an actual proof out of this I will write it up as an answer.

Comment: @bof what I mean by the title is that it seems easy when you see the formulation, but it is actually hard

Comment: @Fishbane Regarding the idea of modular arithmetic: since $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has determinant 3, the sequence will be periodic modulo any number not divislble by 3.  So, that would indicate if modular arithmetic would work, it must be by looking modulo some power of 3.  (But obviously, modulo 3 won't work.  When I tried modulo 27, it looked like the periodic part started with 1, 23, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will work in the ring
$$ R=\Bbb Z[a]\ ,\qquad\text{ where } a=\sqrt{-2}\ .
$$
Then the characteristic equation of the given linear recursion is
$\lambda^2 -2\lambda +3=0$, it has the roots $(1+a)$ and $(1-a)$, both in $R$.
The general formula for $b_n$ is then:
$$
b_n =\frac 1{2a}\Big[\ (1+a)^n -(1-a)^n \ \Big]\ ,
$$
since it is true for $n=0$ and $n=1$, and since it is one and the same linear combination of the $n$-powers of the roots $(1\pm a)$. Let us assume there is some $n$ such that $b_n=\pm 1$. Then we have
$$
\pm 2a = (1+a)^n - (1-a)^n\ ,
$$
and thus $(1+a)^n$ is an element from $R$ of the shape
$$
y\pm 1\cdot a\ ,\qquad\text{ for some suitable } y\in \Bbb Z\ .
$$
Then we also know the conjugate, so the product is:
$$
3^n =(\ (1+a)(1-a)\ )^n=(1+a)^n(1-a)^n=(y+a)(y-a)=y^2-a^2 =y^2+2\ .
$$
This is a relation that lives in $\Bbb Z$, so let us see if it can be satisfied. To reduce some cases, although not needed, let us consider the above relation modulo $13$. Then $3$ has the multiplicative order three, since $3^3 =27=26+1\equiv 1$ modulo $13$. Its powers are $1,3,9$. Which powers are of the shape $x^2+2$ in $\Bbb F_{13}$?
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
y & 0 & \pm 1 & \pm2 & \pm3 &\pm4 &\pm5 &\pm6
\\\hline
y^2 + 2 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 11 & 5 & 1 & 12
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
So there is no match for the nine. Then $n$ is either $n=3m$ or $n=3m+1$.

In the first case, we have $y^2 = 3^{3m}-2$, in the second case after multiplication with nine $(3y)^2=3^{3(m+1)}-18$. So we obtain an integral point on the elliptic curve
$y^2=x^3-2$ or $Y^2=X^3 -18$. The integral points of these elliptic curves can be computed algorithmically, i am using sage:

```
sage: EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, -2]).integral_points()
....: EllipticCurve(QQ, [0, -18]).integral_points()
....: 
[(3 : 5 : 1)]
[(3 : 3 : 1)]
```

so let us see if the power-of-three condition for $x$, respectively $X$ is matched, oh, yes, indeed, (note that sage gives only the integral point with positive second component, except we explicitly claim we also want the other one... well, we know what we are doing...)

- the first point $(x,y)=(3,\pm5)$ on $y^2 = x^3-2$ corresponds to the solution $(\pm5)^2=3^3-2$, matching $3^n=y^2+2$ for $n=3$,
- the second point $(X,Y)=(3,\pm3)$ on $Y^2 = X^3-18$ corresponds to the solution $(\pm3)^2=3^3-18$, we take back the multiplication with nine, matching $3^n=y^2-2$ for $n=1$.

And indeed, we compute for $n=1$ and $n=3$ the values $b_1=1$, given,
$b_3=\frac 1{2a}(\ (1+a)^3-(1-a)^3\ )=\frac 1a(3a+a^3)=3+a^2=1$. (Or use the linear recursion to get $b_2=2b_1-3b_0=2-0=2$, $b_3=2b_2-3b_1=4-3=1$.)

$\square$

Comment: Ok, my aim was actually to solve $3^n = x^2 + 2$ in integers. The use of modulo $13$ is awesome and when you reduce to $Y^2 = X^3 - 2$ and $Y^2 = X^3 - 18$, one can attack them rigorously with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and without the need of Sage. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DesmondMiles Do you want to post a self-contained answer showing the only positive integer solutions to $x^2+2 = 3^n$ are $(1,1)$ and $(5,3)$?

Comment: @mathworker21 ufff unfortunately I am mistaken :( If you try to solve $Y^2 + 18 = X^3$ using $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ the case with $Y$ and $X$ both being multiples of $3$ will be very troubling. One has to deal with the Thue-type equation $A^3 - 6AB^2 - 6A^2B + 4B^3=1$ and to my knowledge, such are intractable with undergraduate methods. So I guess the best we have as a solution is dan_fulea's answer.